# Angular - inputs created by *ngFor causes duplicate values to display when blur event fires

Tags: angular, ngfor, onblur

When a user enters data in the input and tabs, the blur event updates the underlying array used in the *ngFor (1 value). The DOM however shows 2 duplicate values.

See stackblitz for working code showing the issue: 
https://stackblitz.com/github/mpierce5/duplication-error/tree/master

Comment: Use object instead of `array of string`. Also you don't need `(blur)` event, just use the binding angular provides with `ngModel`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @penleychan said, use objects when you need to change an item which ngFor uses. I mean declare your model in this way:

```
this.testList = [
      { value: '-- placeholder --' },
      { value: '-- placeholder --' },
      { value: '-- placeholder --' },
      { value: '-- placeholder --' },
    ];
```

then bind to it like this:

```
  <input
    *ngFor="let testUnit of testList; let i = index"
    (blur)="editItem($event.target.value, i)"
    class="test-input"
    placeholder="Change Me"
    [attr.value]="testUnit.value == '-- placeholder --' ? '': testUnit.value">


  <div class="test-value-area">
    <div class="test-value-area-title">Array Values</div>
    <p *ngFor="let testUnit of testList">{{testUnit.value}}</p>
  </div>
```

For more inforamtion see [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/21914)

Comment: Tested this and it worked, I did have to update editItem() as mentioned by cmelee. Here is a link to a working solution.[link](https://stackblitz.com/github/mpierce5/duplication-error/tree/solution)
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Great answer Fartab. I would only add one more thing, updating the editItem method too:

```
public editItem(value, index: number) {
    this.testList[index] = {"value": value};
}
```